# Filter with multiple geopoints in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

This might be simple, however I am not able to implement or find out the expected query format.

I was able to create the mapping of the `geo_point` data type right from my application. I am also able to query the indices with the geopoint by sending the following query as a part of request body:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "5km",
                    "field_location" : "9.0194,-79.4509"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `field_location` is the name of the field which is of type `geo_point`. This works perfectly fine.

I am not able to find a way in which I can provide multiple `lat/lon` values to the filter and use a `OR` between them. I tried using the `SHOULD` in the query, but not able to find a right way. Any pointers on how to achieve this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was on the right path. The [Bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) for elasticsearch supports the operators. I was just not using it right.

The following query works:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "geo_distance": {
                        "distance": "1km",
                        "field_location": "9.0194,-79.4509"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "geo_distance": {
                        "distance": "1km",
                        "field_location": "8.9972,-79.4985"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```